# Finding words in phrases using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I wanna use regular expression to find phrases that contains 
1 - One of the N words (any)
2 - All the N words (all )

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile(r'.country.|.place')
>>> phrases = ["This is an place", "France is a European country, and a wonderful place to visit", "Paris is a place, it s the capital of the country.side"]

>>> for phrase in phrases:
...     found = re.findall(reg,phrase)
...     print found
...
```

Result:

```
[' place']
[' country,', ' place']
[' place', ' country.']
```

It seems that I am messing around, I need to specify that I need to find a word, not just a part of word in both cases.

Can anyone help by pointing to the issue ?

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve these two regular expressions - check of any of the N words (any) in the phrase 2 - check if  All the N words (all ).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to match entire words, use `\b` to match word boundaries:

```
reg = re.compile(r'\bcountry\b|\bplace\b')
```